# Android app links assetlinks.json configuration error

Tags: applinks, android-deep-link

As part of Android app link implementation according to https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks
we uploaded Digital asset link file assetlinks.json to our prod and test web domais.

https://eyewa.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

and

https://uat.eyewa.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

corresponding.

After implementing Android part it doesn't work for test flavor.
I tried validating the web configuration through the Google API and got these results

https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://eyewa.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls

with successful response.

And

https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://uat.eyewa.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls

With error in response

```
{
  "maxAge": "599.999999940s",
  "debugString": "********************* ERRORS *********************\n* Error: unavailable: Error fetching statements from https://uat.eyewa.com./.well-known/assetlinks.json (which is equivalent to 'https://uat.eyewa.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json'): 404 Not Found [5] while fetching Web statements from https://uat.eyewa.com./.well-known/assetlinks.json (which is equivalent to 'https://uat.eyewa.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json') using download from the web (ID 1).\n",
  "errorCode": [
    "ERROR_CODE_FETCH_ERROR"
  ]
}
```

I appreciate any help in figuring out what is wrong with the test environment assetlinks file configuration.